# How to get the HTML from a HelperResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorgenerator

Update : I submitted this as an issue to RazorGenerator on github with a sample visual studio solution as attachment : https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/issues/105

I am using RazorGenrator, making compiled RazorHelpers, returning   HelperResult for Render methds. Documentation for HelperResult says is for internal use only, so why does RazorGenerator returns HelperResult? Calling either ToString or ToHtmlString causes exceptions.

How is rendered contents of HelperResult can become accessible? This is my code

```
System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult helperResult = CompiledRazorHelpers.MyHelper.Render(TimePickerId, true, model, false);
```

whats the next step for accessing HTML in helperResult ?

Same thing work fine and renders correctly within an MVC project, why?

```
@CompiledRazorHelpers.MyHelper.Render("WE22", true, model, false);
```

Comment: What sort of exceptions do you? Both `ToString` and `ToHtmlString` should work fine.

Comment: @Pranav : submitted this as an issue with a sample visual studio solution as attachment : https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/issues/105